# Request for permission to ask questions on this site

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, reputation

I would like to request permission to ask questions on this site. Mine was rejected due to reputation issue after attempt to submit for the first time.

Comment: I'd suggest starting at the [help] and [tour]

Comment: @ELawrence Welcome :) Feel free to join us in [the pets chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10964/the-litter-box) where we can more easily answer your questions! You can send me a notification that you're there by writing '@henders' in the chat box. The fact that you asked the question here when you weren't sure is a good sign!

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you originally asked [this question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/19291/reputation-points) on the main space.  Which means you could ask questions on the main space about why you could not ask on the main space.  It was not well received, which may now be causing you some issues.

If you have a question about a pet go back to your main space question and edit it to be the question you wanted to ask.  If/when the question is reopened it should clear any issues you are having at Pets SE.

If you are having issues at [one of the sites you joined in October](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/11267/e-lawrence?tab=profile), nothing you do here will allow you to post at those sister sites.